# Java server and socket.io

Tags: java, socket.io, java-server

Are there any examples(ready scripts) to connect to java server with socket.io library?
My problem: I have a server that works on java (proceed some data from clients) and a java client that is always connected to server (server is to be informed when a client is disconnected).
I want to create a javascript extension for google chrome that replace this java client.
But now server and client communicate now with simple text protocol.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several java libraries that provide java's connectivity with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) client.

### Servers

1. [ibdknox/socket.io-netty](https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty) (NOTE: not updated since 2011, not compatible with socket.io v0.7 or above)
2. [avostryakov/Socket.IO-Java](https://github.com/avostryakov/Socket.IO-Java) (a fork of Ovea/Socket.IO-Java which is no longer available)
3. [mrniko/netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio)
4. [Atmosphere/atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) (see [Getting-Started-with-Socket.IO](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Socket.IO))
5. [trinopoty/socket.io-server-java](https://github.com/trinopoty/socket.io-server-java) (based on the [official engine.io Java server](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-server-java) but modified for normal socket.io)

The trinopoty and mrniko servers are both mentioned on [the official docs for socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/index.html) under "other server implementations".

### Clients

1. [Official Java client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)
2. [benkay/java-socket.io.client](https://github.com/benkay/java-socket.io.client) (NOTE: no longer maintained)
3. [Gottox/socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) (NOTE: repository has now been archived)

Comment: Thank you. It's realy helpfull.

Comment: ibdknox/socket.io-netty is outdated: "This project is currently low on my priorities list and likely won't see a lot of attention in the near future. It works with socket.io 0.6, but since socket.io 0.7 was essentially a rewrite, it will require a fair amount of work to continue moving it forward"

Comment: It's been updated now -- works with 1.0 (according to its README).

Comment: @WalrustheCat I don't think so... it is still the same, and hasn't been updated since 2011. probably you are confusing it with the similarly-named "netty-socketio" which ***does*** support v1.0.