# How do I install netty-socketio to my play application?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am very new to scala, play and java. I have to use [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) inside my play application. I have been installing 3rd party plugins via SBT by adding it to appDependencies in project/Build.scala. Incase of netty-socketio there seems to be no direct way of installing  through the resolvers. How do I install it? Help is appreciated.

Comment: If they don't say how to install it, use another library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514767/java-server-and-socket-io#9514998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library is not available in any online repository, you can just create a `lib` folder at the root of your Play! app and drop your jar in it.

It will be added to your classpath by sbt.