# Socket.io connecting with java server

Tags: java, websocket, socket.io

I have developed java server to communicate with clients via TCP. It works with other java clients connecting, however when trying to connect with a socket.io client the server gets only the get request. When the java server ties to post data back to the socket.io client it throws line not available error.

I am using the following code to connect to the java server:

```
var socket = io.connect('URL');

socket.on('connect', function () {
    alert('connected!');
});
```

What do I need to do to get a socket.io client to connect to a java server?

Comment: may be this link can help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514767/java-server-and-socket-io?rq=1

Comment: Do you have to create a completely separate server to work with socket.io on the java end?